How to classify/recognize postage stamp varieties?
As a hobbiest stamp collector, I often run into the need for classifying stamps based on minute differences, such as these:

Now, I literally have thousands of them (in ziploc bags) and I am planning on building an automation platform, that makes a picture and immediately classifies the stamp as one of these varieties. (I make this type of integrated systems for work, so doing it at home is very feasible.)
What I am stuck at, is at identifying what type of image recognition / AI / classical fitting problem this is. It is somewhat made difficult, by the fact that the overall variation between stamps is quite large: cancels can obscure part of the image, there might be damage, color varieties, etc.
This is a representative image of what an algorithm would have to deal with:

I can imagine it to be a step wise approach:

Normalization: crop, rotate and scale the stamp
The hardest part, where any help is appreciated!

